# How to make pytest timeout fail test instead of stopping whole run on windows?

Tags: windows, pytest, timeout

I wonder if there is a possibility for pytest-timeout(or any other solution) to fail timed out test instead of dropping whole run?
Pytest-timeout has timeout method signal which accomplishes exactly what I need but only on Unix systems. Is there anything that might give me same behaviour on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own timeout decorator

```
from threading import Thread
import functools


def timeout(seconds):
    def deco(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = [Exception('function [%s] timeout [%s seconds] exceeded!' % (func.__name__, seconds))]

            def new_func():
                try:
                    res[0] = func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    res[0] = e

            t = Thread(target=new_func)
            t.daemon = True
            try:
                t.start()
                t.join(seconds)
            except Exception as je:
                print('error starting thread')
                raise je
            ret = res[0]
            if isinstance(ret, BaseException):
                raise ret
            return ret

        return wrapper

    return deco

@timeout(2)
def test_x():
    ...
```

Comment: If I have 800 tests already, how can I run this before each?

Comment: @kimor, I assume your test starts with def test_, if that the case then can with your IDE make a find & replace to @timeout(secondes=xxx)\ndef test_

Comment: is there any other way then to add it to each test? I noticed that it works only as @timeout(2)
def test_x():
tried to add it through modifyitems
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, pytest.Function) and not item.nodeid.endswith("()"):
            seconds_before_timeout = 1
            log.info(item.obj)
            item.obj = timeout(seconds_before_timeout)(item.obj)
did not work
tried with 
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def apply_custom_wrapper(request):
    test_func = request.node
    if callable(test_func):
        request.node = timeout(1)(test_func)

Comment: also no errors and dont work

Comment: How would I close these threads? I assume that 900 of them would load the system pretty much

Comment: t.join(seconds). how do you run your tests ? if you use pytest-xdist you can limit the number of  concurrent tests

Comment: I run them 
pytest -s -v -m "marks" --run --show-capture=no --reruns 1 --reruns-delay 5 
there is no concurrent tests, I just saw this solution in other question and there was a warning about threads not being closed